# DynamoDB query secondary index ValidationException: Condition parameter type does not match schema type

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, dynamodb-queries, aws-serverless

I am developing an AWS service using the Serverless Framework.  So far it has one table and a couple global secondary indexes.  I'm trying to query against a global secondary index.

Query:

```
{
    "TableName": "messages-table-dev",
    "IndexName": "roomIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "room = :room",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":room": {
            "S": "everyone"
        }
    }
}
```

It gives an exception -- using the Node.js DynamoDB client, not the Node.js DocumentClient

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
message: 'One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type',
code: 'ValidationException',
time: 2018-06-05T05:11:08.899Z,
requestId: '72OROVKI35I3QDO2IJNQH6SIRVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 35.265782751506215
```

I understand from the documentation that KeyConditionExpression must do an equality match on the partition index.  In this case the `room` field is the partition index of the `roomIndex` global secondary index.  According to the documentation, you substitute values into the expression using the ExpressionAttributeValues array, and as far as I can determine this is constructed correctly.

The exception message is making me think of a type mismatch between the supplied value in the query and the type of the column being queried.  Is that the correct interpretation?  But that cannot be the case - as you can see below, the `room` column is defined as `S` for String.  Hence this is a string comparison and should be fine.

Again - I am not using the DocumentClient.  I've seen plenty of answers suggesting to simplify the query by using that client.  I'm not using it.

The table is defined in the Serverless `serverless.yml` as so:

```
MessagesDynamoDBTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: messageId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: room
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: userId
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: messageId
        KeyType: HASH
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: roomIndex
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: room
            KeyType: HASH
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
      - IndexName: userIndex
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    TableName: ${self:custom.tableName}
```

The table has a simple primary key and then two Global indexes each with simple primary keys.

The query code:

```
const params = {
    TableName: MESSAGES_TABLE,
    IndexName: "roomIndex",
    KeyConditionExpression: "room = :room",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":room": { S: `${req.params.room}` }
    },
};
console.log(`QUERY ROOM ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);

dynamoDb.query(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Could not get messages' });
    } else {
        res.json(result.Items);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`{
    "TableName": "messages-table-dev",
    "IndexName": "roomIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "room = :room",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":room": "everyone"
    }
}`

There is no need of putting data type while querying to dynamoDb

Comment: What you are saying is accurate if I were using the DocumentClient.

In my case, I had been using the DocumentClient but had forgotten the code was using DocumentClient.  As soon as I switched from DocumentClient to DynamoDB, my code began working.  Blush.

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit to a bit of embarrassment.  I said several times in the question that my code was not using the DocumentClient but was using the DynamoDB class.

With DocumentClient, this query does indeed work:

```
{
    "TableName": "messages-table-dev",
    "IndexName": "roomIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "room = :room",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":room": "everyone"
    }
}
```

That's because DocumentClient does not require those data types, and instead it deduces the data types.

Turns out that my code actually was using DocumentClient, and that as soon as I removed the data type from the query the HTTP request worked as expected.  And, when going to the DynamoDB client and adding back the data types, that also worked.

If I had looked more carefully at the application code, this question would never have been posted.

Comment: I'm using the document client. After following your answer, the initial issue mentioned in the ticket was fixed. But now I'm facing a new error(thrown from the query method). "Error: ID is not defined". ID is the primary key of my table. I'm trying to query by secondary global index column. Any idea?